# How can I put a Kendo DateTimePicker inside a Kendo dialog? (Telerik UI/Kendo for ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to put two [Kendo UI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telerik#Controls_Suite) elements inside one another and it doesn't allow me. How can I fix the syntax error?

```
@(Html.Kendo().Dialog()
    .Name("MyModal")
    .Title("much wow")
    .Content(
            @(Html.Kendo().DateTimePicker()
            .Name("dateTimePicker")
            )
        )
    .Width(400)
    .Modal(false)
    .Actions(actions =>
        {
            actions.Add().Text("asd");
            actions.Add().Text("qwe");
            actions.Add().Text("zxc").Primary(true);
        }
    )
)
```

[Syntax error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2J3zd.png)

I need a popup/modal/dialogue window with a DateTimePicker and a TextBox, and two buttons; <kbd>Cancel</kbd> and <kbd>Accept</kbd>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out;

```
@(
Html.Kendo().Dialog()
    .Name("MyModal")
    .Title("much wow")
    .Content(
            Html.Kendo().DateTimePicker()
            .Name("MyModalDateTimePicker") // name is the id
            .ToHtmlString() +
            Html.Kendo().TextBox()
            .Name("MyModalTextBox") // name is the id
            .Value("John Doe")
            .ToHtmlString()
    )
    .Width(400)
    .Modal(false)
    .Actions(actions =>
        {
            actions.Add().Text("Cancel");
            actions.Add().Text("OK").Primary(true);
        }
    )
)
```